# Как создать спиннер?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Как создать спиннер на андроид чтобы когда нажимаешь на любую строку спиннера меня перекидывали на другую страницу?

Comment: Очевидно что в обработчике спинера убрать данный функционал.

Answer (score 1):

Пример работы со `Spinner`'ом можно найти [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/115-urok-56-spinner-vypadajuschij-spisok.html). Переход на новую активити, надо будет делать внутри метода `onItemSelected`.

Примеры работы с несколькими активити можно найти [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/58-urok-21-sozdanie-i-vyzov-activity.html). В зависимости от того, какой элемент был выбран, создавайте `Intent` с классом нужной активити и переходите на неё с помощью метода `startActivity` (как в примере).